# WordPress automated script to sync Staging and Production Database on daily basis

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, synchronization, wp-cli

I am looking for an automated way to sync my Staging database with the Production database on a daily basis.
There are multiple plugins that provide manual one-click solutions. 
Has anyone here found any automated way to solve this, 
for eg - a script using WP-CLI.

Comment: I would advise against using any kind of WP plugin to achieve this. You should use some kind of [MySQL replication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65351/sync-two-mysql-databases-in-two-different-locations)

Comment: [MySQL Replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html)